# Override default options in plugin metaboxes

Tags: jquery, metabox, wp-admin

Imagine you are on a post-new page to add a post, and a metabox added by a plugin has a lot of checkboxes that always need to be checked manually.

Here is one of them:

```
    <div class="form_item form_item_checkbox form_item_plainview_form2_inputs_checkboxes_blogs_5 ">
        <input class="checkbox" id="plainview_form2_inputs_checkboxes_blogs_5" name="broadcast[blogs][blogs_5]" type="checkbox" value="5">
        <label for="plainview_form2_inputs_checkboxes_blogs_5">Some item I need to be checked by default</label>
    </div>
```

I´d like to have this checked by default every time the page is loaded. I don't want to modify the plugin code.

I suppose a jquery would be the most flexible way to approach this problem.
Any advice on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as example of js code that will run on every new post page

```
    function admin_footer_se_119285(){
        ?>
            jQuery(window).ready(function(){
                if (jQuery('#metabox-id-div').length == 1){
                    // put your code
                }
            })

        <?php
    }
?>
```

Take a look to usefull [reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_footer-%28plugin_page%29) to admin_footer-(plugin_page) action hook

Comment: You're missing the `<script>` tag. And in this case it should be `add_action( 'admin_footer-post.php', 'admin_footer_se_119285' );` and `post-new.php` too.

Comment: correct! miss it =)